# Validating IP address by regular expression - Unknown escape sequence

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I am working on an iOS project that require using regular expression to validate ipv4 address.

I use following code

```
// only support ip4 currently
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$"
                              options:0
                              error:nil];

NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:IpString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [IpString length])];
return (numberOfMatches==1?TRUE:FALSE);
```

XCode keep warning me "unknown escape sequence .". When return true when I type "1.3.6.-6" or "2.3.33".

How can I use dot(.) in regex? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to double backslash your `.`, as the first backslash is being interpreted by NSString, and it's looking for an escape character for `.` (which doesn't exist). Double backslashing (`\\.`) will cause the first backslash to escape the second backslash (which does exist), meaning you can use `\` normally.

So for example, your regex will be:

```
@"^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$"
```